# android autoscaling images vs custom scaling

Tags: android, performance, android-image

I have read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), which explains the idea of providing images with several resolutions for the different dpi´s(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, ...).

The site also explains that the idea behind this is that the images look similar on the different devices.

However, in the article is also mentioned that by using this mechanism the images are not exactly the same size on all devices, because each dpi class has a range of dpi´s, which fall into that class.
So for example, hdpi ranges from 180 dpi to 280 dpi ( This is not exact, the values are just for comprehension)

That´s what I cannot understand. **Why use this autoscaling and make the images only appear similar on different devices, while you could scale them yourself on-the-fly and have exact results.**

I mean 1 aspect could be that scaling on the fly could take to much resources, but I think with today´s modern resources the scaling should not be too hard.

So, could someone please explain me, why it it suggested to use autoscaling over custom scaling.

Additionally some best practices and experience from others would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution for my case.

I decided that i will use percentage measurements for my UI elements, so my UI elements won´t be the same physical size on all devices, but my UI will fit on all screens - which is my single goal!

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pre-scaled images you have no performace cost on the device. The images are quite small so the memory price is negligible. Imagine having to scale a huge image to a small icon on an older device. The bitmap would not be able to fit in reserved RAM.

Pre-made images will always look better compared to rescaled. If you take proper care. You can create smaller images by automatic scaling but afterwards you can take a pencil tool and refine edges.

The images won't physically have the same size, but the screen sizes and ratios vary too. You want to setup your layouts in such way, that the text area size changes not the image size (or font size).

Best practice is written in the article you provided: create various sizes of resources depending on dpi bucket.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, however i do not understand what you mean with "You want to setup your layouts in such way, that the text area size changes not the image size (or font size)."